# cordova build android does not working in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, sdk

I am trying to generate my production apk in ionic, however when I run the command cordova build android it returns the following error

[image: error image]

I already configured the environment variables, I installed the gradle I put the tools folder inside the SDK but it did not work

This is the current location of my sdk C: \ Users \ Mike \ AppData \ Local \ Android \ android-sdk

[image: This is SDK Path]

Comment: Please add text of error message and not image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the environment variable **PATH**, which should includes these locations:

```
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\28.0.1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to solve my app and generate the apk, my path was wrong indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced the same issue. may be due to gradle.

It is occurs becasue you tried to open that project in android studio.

Step i followed to solve the issue :
1. remove android platform from ionic project.
2. Again add platform Android in your ionic project.
3. try to run your android project by "ionic cordova run android"

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: i'm use ionic v1